# Next LTS distro release

Tags: distro-recommendation

Just curious as to when the next LTS distro release will be.  Running 18.04 at the moment, and, though I'm happy with it, I'm just ready for the next one. I understand the difference between LTS and Normal releases, just unsure of the release scheduling itself.

Comment: 20.04 will be LTS which is scheduled to release in April 2020.

Comment: fyi:  18.04 means the 2018.April release (ie. main Ubuntu releases are *yy.mm* in format), so 20.04 means 2020.April.   Some releases are *yy* in format only, eg. Ubuntu Core 18 refers to the 2018 Ubuntu Core release (a specialized IoT appliance release).   Release are April & October, thus .04 & .10 (with exception of 2006.June release as that first LTS release was late)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LTS are published every two years. The current one is 18.04 so the next one will be 20.04. From Ubuntu's [website](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle):

> LTS or ‘Long Term Support’ releases are published every two years in
>   April.